# Expandable list view, child on click new activity with information

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

This might be very easy question, but I'm looking for your help.
I'm using downloaded open source file. I have a list of Groups with populated Child's under it. I'm able to expand the list and see the Child's. How could I open new activity window with text information relater for specific Children when clicking on it?

Thank you for support.

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.expandablelistviewsearch;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener; 
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements

        SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, SearchView.OnCloseListener {

    private SearchView search;
    private MyListAdapter listAdapter;
    private ExpandableListView myList;
    private ArrayList<Continent> continentList = new ArrayList<Continent>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myList.setOnChildClickListener(myListItemClicked); //added line

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        search = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search);
        search.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
                .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        search.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
        search.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        //search.setOnCloseListener(this);

        // display the list
        displayList();
        // expand all Groups
        //expandAll();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    // method to expand all groups
    private void expandAll() {
        int count = listAdapter.getGroupCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            myList.expandGroup(i);
        }
    }
    private OnChildClickListener myListItemClicked =  new OnChildClickListener() {

        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

            //get the group header
            HeaderInfo headerInfo = deptList.get(groupPosition);
            //get the child info
            DetailInfo detailInfo =  headerInfo.getProductList().get(childPosition);
            //start new activity with specific child information

            return false;
        }

    };
    // method to expand all groups
    private void displayList() {

        // display the list
        loadSomeData();

        // get reference to the ExpandableListView
        myList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableList);
        // create the adapter by passing your ArrayList data
        listAdapter = new MyListAdapter(MainActivity.this, continentList);
        // attach the adapter to the list
        myList.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    }

            private void loadSomeData() {
            ArrayList<Country> countryList = new ArrayList<Country>();
            Country country = new Country("Test1", "Test2", "Test3");
            countryList.add(country);

            Continent continent = new Continent("Main Test", countryList);
            continentList.add(continent);


            private void loadSomeData() {
            ArrayList<Country> countryList = new ArrayList<Country>();
            Country country = new Country("Test1", "Test2", "Test3");
            countryList.add(country);

            Continent continent = new Continent("Main Tes1t", countryList);
            continentList.add(continent);


            private void loadSomeData() {
            ArrayList<Country> countryList = new ArrayList<Country>();
            Country country = new Country("Test1", "Test2", "Test3");
            countryList.add(country);

            Continent continent = new Continent("Main Test2", countryList);
            continentList.add(continent);

        }


        @Override
        public boolean onClose() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            listAdapter.filterData("");
            //expandAll();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            listAdapter.filterData(newText);
            expandAll();
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            listAdapter.filterData(query);
            expandAll();
            return false;
        }

    }
```

MyListAdapter.java

```
package com.example.expandablelistviewsearch;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Continent> continentList;
    private ArrayList<Continent> originalList;

    public MyListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Continent> continentList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.continentList = new ArrayList<Continent>();
        this.continentList.addAll(continentList);
        this.originalList = new ArrayList<Continent>();
        this.originalList.addAll(continentList);
    }
    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList<Country> countryList = continentList.get(groupPosition).getCountryList();
        return countryList.get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Country country = (Country) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        if(convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_row, null);
        }

        TextView code = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.code);
        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView fdd = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fdd);
        code.setText(country.getCode().trim());
        name.setText(country.getName().trim());
        fdd.setText(country.getFdd().trim());
        //population.setText(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(country.getPopulation()));

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList<Country> countryList = continentList.get(groupPosition).getCountryList();
        return countryList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return continentList.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return continentList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Continent continent = (Continent) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if(convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.group_row, null);
        }

        TextView heading = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.heading);
        heading.setText(continent.getName().trim());

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    public void filterData(String query)
    {
        query = query.toLowerCase();
        Log.v("MyListAdapter", String.valueOf(continentList.size()));
        continentList.clear();

        if(query.isEmpty())
        {
            continentList.addAll(originalList);
        } else {
            for(Continent continent: originalList)
            {
                ArrayList<Country> countryList = continent.getCountryList();
                ArrayList<Country> newList = new ArrayList<Country>();
                for(Country country: countryList)
                {
                    if(country.getCode().toLowerCase().contains(query) || country.getName().toLowerCase().contains(query))
                    {
                        newList.add(country);
                    }
                }
                if(newList.size() > 0)
                {
                    Continent nContinent = new Continent(continent.getName(), newList);
                    continentList.add(nContinent);
                }
            }
        }

        Log.v("MyListAdapter", String.valueOf(continentList.size()));
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, under your code, you can send anything related to the child you click to the new activity using intent, then get the information out in the new activity

```
private OnChildClickListener myListItemClicked =  new     OnChildClickListener() {

    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

        //get the group header
        HeaderInfo headerInfo = deptList.get(groupPosition);
        //get the child info
        DetailInfo detailInfo =  headerInfo.getProductList().get(childPosition);
        //start new activity with specific child information
        //--Add below codes to your code 
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TargetActivity.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("information",detailInfo.getInfor());
        return false;
    }

};
```

In the TargetActivity,

```
    Intent tIntent= getIntent();
    Bundle b = tIntent.getExtras();
    String information = (String)b.get("information");
```

The string information is probably what you want to display